# 415 Unsupported Media Type Error being returned when posting to API through C# class

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

I am trying to write a class that will post a json object to an API.  If I post the following through Postman (passing it as raw json), the API responds with a 200:

```
[{"Id":"1","Name":"First of Two","obdOdometer":{"Time":"2020-01-01","Value":"112233"}},{"Id":"2","Name":"Second of Two","obdOdometer":{"Time":"2020-02-03","Value":"45506"}}]
```

However, I am getting errors when using my class.

Here is the class I am trying to use:

```
        public async Task TransmitobdOdometer(string json)
        {

            string bearerToken = _config.GetSection("PilotTmwApiSettings:BearerToken").Value;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
                var res = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44308/TestDev", new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { json } )));

                try
                {
                    res.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

The string being passed into TransmitobdOdometer() is formatted like so:

```
string odometerValues = "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"First of Two\",\"obdOdometer\":{\"Time\":\"2020-01-01\",\"Value\":\"112233\"}},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"Second of Two\",\"obdOdometer\":{\"Time\":\"2020-02-03\",\"Value\":\"45506\"}}]";
```

This returns the error message: "Response status code does not indicate success: 415 (Unsupported Media Type)."  I tried adjusting the format of the string being passed in, but I get the same error, so I figured I'd ask for insight into what I may be doing wrong before proceeding further.

Comment: have you tried settng the `Content-Type` to `application/json`?

Comment: I changed the one line to use application/json (see below) and now I am getting an error 400:  var res = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44308/TestDev", new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { json } ), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

Comment: so thats a different case

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line to

```
var res = client.PostAsync("localhost:44308/TestDev", new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { json } ), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

... fixed the error 415.  I am still getting an error, but will move that to a new discussion.